# React native - How to do such transition animations?

Tags: react-native, animation, navigation, transition

How do I implement such transition animations like in this example in react native?

https://dribbble.com/shots/7164639-Interactive-restaurant-recommendations-app

Are there any libraries that could manage that or can somebody explain how to implement something similar step by step?

I do not expect any working code, just some hints for libraries/steps

This are my thoughts:

1. I have a stack navigator.
2. Then there is a library like react-navigation-transitions, which could help to implement a nice transition
3. some animations in componentDidMount
4. Maybe use some shared elements

But I don't know if this guide could implement such nice fluent transitions like in example above.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For the cards try to use [react-native-tinder-swipe-cards](https://github.com/meteor-factory/react-native-tinder-swipe-cards) and for the other animations use [react-native-animatable](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-animatable)